# Getting error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Here's the method I was trying to use:

```
private void UpdateDataInTable(string tableName, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
     try
     {
         int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Medicineid"].Value);
         string newValue = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString();
         if (dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].ValueType == typeof(decimal))
         {
             decimal decimalValue;
             if (decimal.TryParse(newValue, out decimalValue))
             {
                 newValue = decimalValue.ToString();
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Wrong format of number.");
                 return;
             }
         }
         string query = $"UPDATE {tableName} SET {dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].Name} = @newValue WHERE Medicineid = @id";

         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             connection.Open();

             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
             {
                 // Передача параметров в SQL-запрос
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", newValue);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

                 // Выполнение SQL-запроса
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error occured while upgrading values: " + ex.Message);
     }
}
```

I was trying to write a method to upgrade my database table if I change cell value and I have column of decimal values. This is where the error converting data type nvarchar to numeric occurs.

Comment: Sorry, our crystal ball is not working today. You will need to supply more info. What is the exact error (exception) message? What line of code did the error occur on? What was the value that it was attempting to convert. If the ExecuteNonQuery was returning an error, what was the column name being updated? What is the associated table definition? What is the NVARCHAR value or column that you mentioned? What are the parameter values being passed? Have you tried executing the equivalent statement directly against the database (using SSMS)? What else have you attempted so far to debug the issue?

Comment: Consider specifying correct data types and length/precision/scale when adding parameters to `SqlCommand`s. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) ...and... [AddWithValue is Evil.](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Medicineid"].Value);
string newValue = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString();
if (dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].ValueType == typeof(decimal))
{
    var style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
    Decimal decimalValue;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(newValue, style, culture, out decimalValue))
    {
        newValue = decimalValue.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong format of number.");
        return;
    }
}
```